# WP8 SQL CE 4.0 database deployment error "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format"

Tags: windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I added a SQLCE 4.0 database (sdf file) into my WP 8 project, it works fine initially, I can deploy the app to device.
But after some data is populated to the database ( the size of the db increase from 120kb to 4 MB), I can't deploy it to device, it failed with message "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format".
If I swap the database with the empty one, it works again.

Thanks in advance for any advice....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a desktop database, it must be 3.5 format

Comment: Your are right. Although still can't explain why it accept a empty 4.0 database.....

Comment: Apparently the engine always expects 3.5 files (remember that including a database file created on desktop is not supported)